# android app still keeps acceleration sensor registered

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, power-management

I've got a problem with the acceleration sensor of my app. It all works fine and reads values and so on... But the sensor is keeping alive, after finishing the activity! With an app like [GSam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gsamlabs.bbm) I noticed that my App is still consuming!

I think that I did the register and unregister Process correctly, actually the Magnetic Field and Orientation sensor is unregistered properly.

HOW CAN I GET RID OF THAT SENSOR? PLEASE HELP!

See source code below (kept only the register / unregister things):

```
    package com.acceler;



    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Vibrator;
    import android.hardware.*;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.*;



    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        SensorManager sensorManager;



        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
            WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display mDisplay = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay();


        } /* End onCreate activity */

        private SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {



            }

            /* Get the Sensors */
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

                  switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
                         case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                                  System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mGravs, 0, 3);
                                  break;
                         case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                                  System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mGeoMags, 0, 3);
                                  break;
                         case Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION:
                                System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mOldOreintation, 0, 3);
                          break;

                         default:
                                  return;
                }
                  if (mprefix == "  ***"){
                  // Get instance of Vibrator from current Context
                  Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);          
                    // Vibrate for 50 milliseconds
                  v.vibrate(50);
                  //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sensor unreliable!", 500).show();



                  }


            }
        };

        private void stopit(){
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener,sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER));
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener,sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD));
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener,sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION));

        }

        @Override
         protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
            sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
            sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
         }


        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();

            stopit();
        }


        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDestroy();
            stopit();
        }


        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onStop();
            stopit();
        }    

    }
```

Comment: Your code is fine. I would not worry about what GSam reports.

Comment: I think GSam is right because my battery is drained!

Comment: Is there any way to check on eclipse ?

Comment: First in the stopit method you only need to call sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener); Second what is the phone system settings battery says about your app.